# How come GSRC's last release was in 2014, but gcc-9 is a package?

Tags: gcc, gnu, version

The GNU Source Release Collection, [gsrc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsrc/), had its latest release in 2014, see [here](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/gsrc/) or [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsrc/). Yet, its [package page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsrc/package-list.html) suggests various new packages, like gcc-9.

What gives? Is the gsrc itself accessing newer packages than its own release, or am I missing something?

Comment: Why shouldn't the components have newer releases?

Answer (score 1):

There haven’t been any “official” releases for a long time, but [the collection is still updated](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/gsrc/trunk/changes/), which is why it includes recent packages.

[The installation instructions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsrc/) aren’t based on a specific release of GSRC; they use whatever is the current tip of the repository. The package list reflects the latter, not the last release.

In GSRC’s case, a single repository is used both for the GSRC tools and the package metadata (and build descriptions). To get up-to-date packages, you need to update to the current tip of the trunk repository anyway (see the last paragraph in the “How to use” section); that’s the GSRC equivalent of `apt update` etc. So there’s not much point in identifying specific releases.

Comment: Does that mean that there has been no need for an update of gsrc itself? Because it's rare that a software package goes 6 years without a release while other aspects of it get  updated.

Comment: There have been updates to the GSRC tools themselves, but because they are part of the same repository as the package metadata, there isn’t much point in making a separate release.

Comment: So, when I install gsrc - from the latest tarball I can download - I don't see the newly-updated packages.

Comment: Yes, because the package metadata is part of the repository (and snapshots thereof, which is what the tarball provides). See the instructions: you need to update the repository if you want updated packages. Admittedly the instructions don’t work too well if you start from a tarball...